# WooCommerce: How To Get Order ID & Total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Maybe someone can help me in this forum? So, i have to put on thank-you.php page pixel for tracking leads.

Pixel is like in this format:

```
<img src="https://example.com/path/slug=*ORDERID*&slug=*TOTAL*" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

There in **ORDERID** i need to get order id without “#” and in **TOTAL** i have to get order total without currency symbol.

So it have to look like:

```
<img src="https://example.com/path/slug=123456&slug=125.00" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Order ID #123456 and order total amount 125.00€.

Before updating WooCommerce to 3.0 it was working fine with this snippet:

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqHzt.jpg)

Now it’s not working.
I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: The URL looks strange... `/slug=1234&slug=125.00`. Shouldn't this be `?order=1234&total=125.00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for WooCommerce 3.0 and later:

```
<?php 
printf(
    '<img src="https://example.com/path/order=%s&total=%s" width="1" height="1" border="0" />',
    $order->get_id(),
    $order->get_total()
); 
?>
```

Comment: Hey, url was just example :) Thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 4):

```
$order->get_formatted_order_total()
```

Gives total with currency symbol.

```
$order->get_total()
```

Gives total without currency symbol.